# How does following image processing functions work?

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have been assigned to project of making custom photo/image editor for one company and when looking at the list of desired functionality I've found out I'm at loss how some of them work. Can anyone please explain how some of it is done/what functions are they?

**Can you please explain it for idiot like me?(practically no prior knowledge of photo editing)**

***(Also if you know about libraries that has those functions I'd be very grateful if you could recommend some, but not necessarily)***

Here's the list:

- White balance editation of RAW (As shot/Auto/Presets/Manual-numerical/Grey card)
- **Exposure**
- **Recovery**
- Fill Light
- Blacks ("making black pixels more black")
- **Clarity/Microcontrast**
- **Saturation**
- **Vibrance**
- Curves
- Levels
- **Sharpening**
- **Color Balance**
- Avoiding color clipping
- Avoiding highlight clipping
- editing brightness but not colors (not sure about how to call this one - in LAB lightness channel)
- Selective color corrections
- **Freemasking**
- **Chromatic abberation**

**P.S.:If there is a stackexchange page more suitable for this question please tell me where to ask!**

Comment: If there is a stackexchange page more suitable for this question please tell me where to ask!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Perhaps have a look at the GIMP source code http://developer.gimp.org/git.html for some inspiration

Comment: I know, I'm asking in hope that there is someone who can explain humanly how these functions work (and maybe finding a library that contains some of them) :)

Comment: You can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **White blance**: you can find more adequate explanations [here](http://www.nikondigital.org/articles/white_balance.htm) and
   [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974166/implement-white-balance-algorithm-from-wiki) treat it nicely (on wikipedia it says that white
   and color balance are similar)
2. **Exposure**: [OpenCV info](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/exposure_compensation.html); It is how many light it is entering through the diaphragm of the device: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_%28photography%29)
3. **Recovery**: Wiki says [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_recovery), but it could be something like [deblurring](http://doc.gold.ac.uk/uk-korea-geomod2011/Slides/05-Seungyong-Lee.pdf)
4. **Fill light**: I think it is something like [shadow remover](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2247/8992)
5. **Blacks**: I do not know what it may be, but it makes me think of inverse of exposure (multiply by negative values)
6. **Clarity/Microcontrast**: [This](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/what-is-micro-contrast-and-how-is-it-different-from-regular-contrast) is a good explanation
7. **Saturation**: is about [color saturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness)
8. **Vibrance**: [A nice explanation](http://digital-photography-school.com/vibrance-vs-saturation-in-plain-english/)
9. **Curves**: I am not sure what it is about: detecting or correcting?
10. **Levels**: I do not know what it is about
11. **Sharpening**: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv) It is about accentuating the edges in an image
12. **Color Balance**: see white balance
13. **Avoiding color clipping**: I think it is base on [this](http://www.macprovideo.com/hub/photoshop/photoshop-cs6-avoiding-clipping-while-correcting-color) idea
14. **Avoiding highlight clipping**: It should be the same as the above, but linked of luminance, instead of color. See the [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28photography%29) theory.
15. **editing brightness but not colors**: I think it is about [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction)
16. **Selective color corrections**: It should be like white balance, but on RGB levels; see [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/16258/color-correction/)
17. **Freemasking**: is based on replacing the "green panel" with what you want, as in television
18. **Chromatic abberation**: is because of the lens of the device: see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration)

Comment: You sir/lady, saved my ass! I'm a bit ashamed that +1 and answer is the only thing I can give you now. I'd treat you a lunch :)